# best way to create file in word2vec format to pass to spacy init model?

Tags: python, spacy, word2vec

I have a homegrown embedding model I have built. I am trying to load my word vectors in spacy (using the init-model CLI) and therefore need to reformat my vectors output as a word2vec table which from my understanding is: first line is shape of vectors and the following lines are "word" <word_embedding>.

My question (and maybe it is a stupid one), is there a way that I can write word as a string (with parentheses) and the raw vector? My current file is "word <word_vector>" so when the file is parsed the word vector is a string which is not desirable.

The code I am trying to conform to is (spacy init-model):

```py
def read_vectors(vectors_loc, truncate_vectors=0):
    f = open_file(vectors_loc)
    shape = tuple(int(size) for size in next(f).split())
    if truncate_vectors >= 1:
        shape = (truncate_vectors, shape[1])
    vectors_data = numpy.zeros(shape=shape, dtype="f")
    vectors_keys = []
    for i, line in enumerate(tqdm(f)):
        line = line.rstrip()
        pieces = line.rsplit(" ", vectors_data.shape[1])
        word = pieces.pop(0)
        if len(pieces) != vectors_data.shape[1]: # <- pieces is a string!
            msg.fail(Errors.E094.format(line_num=i, loc=vectors_loc), exits=1)
        vectors_data[i] = numpy.asarray(pieces, dtype="f") # <- will literally create a array of length 1 dtype=object
        vectors_keys.append(word)
        if i == truncate_vectors - 1:
            break
    return vectors_data, vectors_keys
```

I know I could pretty easily start hacking up the init-model code if need be, but I would really rather not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd help to show your existing attempt to write a (short, few vectors) file, and its output, and contrast it with an example file of a few vectors in the desired format. Also, looking at other projects' code for *writing* that format may be more instructive than SpaCY's import-only code. The gensim project's method for writing that format goes by `save_word2vec_format()`, & the core of its implementation in the current codebase is at: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/a811a231747ba5b089d74c4bc22e8f419874baa1/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py#L105

Answer (score 0):

End of the day and a bit of a doofus moment.

If anyone else is has troubles passing vectors to Spacy... you can actually pass the vectors as a numpy `.npz` file in sofar that you also pass the `--json-loc` file (as the json lines file has the `id` idx into the word vectors).

A bit weird as I have always serialized my numpy with a `.npy` extension but nonetheless.

Hope this helps someone!